# Dojo/Dijit: Can't get filtering select to work

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a page with some JavaScript and it includes dojo.parser and has parseOnLoad set to true and whatnot.

Later in the page, I have another JavaScript tag that has:

```
dojo.require('dijit.form.FilteringSelect');
dojo.registry.remove('ID OF SELECT BOX');
```

After all that, I have a select box with dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect".

Whenever I load the page, I get:

> undefined Could not load class 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect'. Did you spell the name correctly and use a full path, like 'dijit.form.Button'?

Any ideas why?  If I put the require statement in the first JavaScript tag, it works (but that tag is in a more global file, so I don't want it there).

Comment: Can you please post the second, non-working JavaScript block, including the surrounding tags?  Can you get any other JavaScript [like a test alert() or console.log()] to run successfully in that second block?

Comment: It sounds like the parser is running before that dojo.require() takes effect.   But like Abboq said it's hard to know why from your limited description above.

The dojo.registry.remove() is also weird, you should not be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

dojo.registry is not correct. we have only **dijit.registry.remove** function. Maybe that is causing the problem.